# Need explanation of the output

Tags: c, c++14

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int b[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int n =&b[3]-&a[2];
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

please, anyone, explain why the **output is showing 5**.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, so anything could be output. Pointer arithmetic is only valid for elements of the ***same*** array.

Comment: Unrelated: Choose _one_ language. Are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: You might add what output you expect instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Pointer arithmetic is not defined between unrelated objects.

What you observe is that in your implementation the arrays `a` and `b` are laid out contiguously and that explains the difference 5. But this is by no means a guaranteed behaviour and doing the pointer arithmetic in itself is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since pointer arithmetic is only valid for elements of the same array as already pointed out, let's start by making the program valid. You can do that by casting the pointers to an integer capable of holding a pointer value, for example a `std::uintptr_t`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int b[4]={1,2,3,4};
    auto diff = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&b[3]) -
                reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&a[2]);
    std::cout
        << diff << '\n'
        << diff / sizeof(int) << '\n'
    ;
}
```

Possible output:

```
20
5
```

This means that the address difference between `b[3]` and `a[2]` is 20 and that there is room for 5 `int`s in that address space.

Comment: You should mention that this program still is undefined bahaviour.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You mean that `&b[3]` could be less than `&a[2]`? The result is implementation defined, but I don't see the UB.

Comment: Isn't pointer arithmetic between unrelated objects UB?

Comment: @Jabberwocky After the `reinterpret_cast`, they are just integers so there is no pointer arithmetic going on at all in the program.

Comment: Good point, but the output you get may be total nonsens, although your explanation makes perfectly sense on most platforms.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, you get a diff between two integers that could be essentially anything I guess.